# PHP program how to combine lengths to get closer to the summary

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

im trying to solve this in Php
i have a cable in total we can call it  L = 15 , (by a variable $total_lenght for ex)
i have to cut L  in 2 or more different  cable_length , but equal pieces
im looking for the combination of cut to give me the less modulo.

i get an array like that

```
`$array_rws =intval(count($tabl_new));`
```

at this point we have 2

```
`array (size=2) 
0 =\> 
array (size=6)
'cable_length' =\> float 0.6 
'pieces' =\> int 0 
'modulo' =\> float 0 
1 =\> 
array (size=6) 
'cable_length' =\> float 1.6
'pieces' =\> int 0
'modulo' =\> float 0`
```

i hope that reverse technic may help, x and y are unknown

```
(x * cable_length1) + (y * cable_length2) = L ( , var name $total_lenght) 

(9 * 0.6 ) + (6 * 1.6) = 15
```

i take from array the cable_length1 and cable_length2. Another one variable $total_lenght gives the L

can we make a loop, using for to find out the multiplier ?
And to put values to 'pieces' and to 'modulo'  if we have some

im trying to find the combination
another one point that makes it more difficult is that the array is dynamic and maybe we have more that three or more cable lengths.

I will sort this array by modulo at the end.

thanks for your time

i tried to make a loop in a loop but i confused
i dont know how to manage if there a 3,4 or more cable lengths...

Answer (score 0):

You want the best combination of integers that will get as close as possible to L while solving `x*a1 + y*a2 + ... + z*a3 = L`.
First, let's solve for 3 parts. I will use JS for the interactivity.

```js
function findClosestIntegerSolution(a1, a2, a3, L) {
  let best = Infinity;
  let xMin, yMin, zMin;

  for (let x = 0; x <= L; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= L; y++) {
      for (let z = 0; z <= L; z++) {
        const dist = L - (x * a1 + y * a2 + z * a3);
        if (dist >= 0 && dist < best) {
          best = dist;
          xMin = x;
          yMin = y;
          zMin = z;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    x: xMin,
    y: yMin,
    z: zMin
  };
}

const a1 = 1.6;
const a2 = 0.6;
const a3 = 0;
const L = 15;

const solution = findClosestIntegerSolution(a1, a2, a3, L);
console.log(solution);
```

Now the fun part, we'll use it for size `n`. This time with recursion because of the nature of the problem. We will hold an array for the solution [0,0,0, ...0] and keep incrementing the counters, checking each combination for the best match to the equation.

```js
function distance(vector_a, solution, L) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < vector_a.length; i++) {
    total += vector_a[i] * solution[i]
  }
  return L - total;
}

function findClosestIntegerSolution(vector_a, L) {
  let best = Infinity;
  let k = vector_a.length;
  let counters = new Array(k).fill(0)
  let solution = new Array(k).fill(0)

  function iterateCounters(position) {
    if (position === k) {
      const dist = distance(vector_a, counters, L);
      if (dist >= 0 && dist < best) {
        best = dist;
        solution = [...counters];
      }
    } else {
      for (let value = 0; value <= L; value++) {
        counters[position] = value;
        
        // move "right" to try all combinations 
        iterateCounters(position + 1);
      }
    }
  }

  iterateCounters(0)

  return solution
}

const a1 = 1.6;
const a2 = 0.6;
const a3 = 0;
const L = 15;

const solution = findClosestIntegerSolution([a1, a2, a3], L);
console.log(solution);
```